# objc to swift conversion

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have the following delegate function I need to implement in swift.

```
-(void) remoteController:(DJIRemoteController*)rc didUpdateGpsData:(DJIRCGPSData)gpsData;
```

I'm not sure what the function should look like.

I have the following, but I think It's wrong.

```
@objc func didUpdateGpsData(rc: DJIRemoteController, gpsData: DJIRCGPSData)
{
    debugMessage.value = String("RC Time : \(gpsData.mTime)")
}
```

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? What results do you get, and what are you expecting?

Comment: When you start typing the function, doesn't it autocomplete the name and function body? And you definitely don't need `@objc` in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, your delegate method would be declared like this:

```swift
func remoteController(_ rc: DJIRemoteController,
        didUpdateGpsData gpsData: DJIRCGPSData)
```

So you would implement it like this:

```swift
func remoteController(rc: DJIRemoteController,
        didUpdateGpsData gpsData: DJIRCGPSData) {
    debugMessage.value = String("RC Type: \(gpsData.mTime\)")
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that this is correct and works. Much appreciated!